# Make payment method active only for API

Tags: payment-methods, enterprise-1.14, soap-api-v1

To start I have already modified the check/money order payment method to be available only in admin (That worked, but not via the API)

The problem is that the method is not available to the V1 API. 
Here is how I am setting the cart

```
$cart = $proxy->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create', 0);
```

(Store 0 is Admin)

```
$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_payment.list", array($cart));
```

Where I get my list of methods only those available on the frontend are working. What I need is a method that is only available via the API.

Comment: I did something similar here https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_AdminMoney where you can select Check/Money order from the admin. Maybe you can use some code from there, definitely not an answer.

Comment: We already have it restricted to admin only, the problem is that it is not available on the frontend using the API

Comment: are you using the observer like mbalparda? Is the observer called when you call the api?

Comment: Yes I installed that module and the payment method is still not available via the API

Comment: Can you combine Miguel's code with this check to ensure the current session is an API call? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033788/can-i-detect-if-a-magento-function-is-being-run-as-an-api-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked!

```
$apiRunning = Mage::getSingleton('api/server')->getAdapter() != null;
```

Thank you for your help.